# Xarray dataset to Pandas dataframe too slow with new xarray library updates

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I am trying to convert an xarray Dataset to a Pandas dataframe. It used to take minutes, but after an xarray library update, it takes hours.

I read in a list of 40 large netcdf datasets (each dataset is 1GB, totaling 40GB) using the command:

```
with xr.open_mfdataset(infile_list, combine='by_coords') as ds:
```

The data has lon, lat, day, crs dimensions. I select a single lat and lon slice using the command:

```
station = ds.sel(lon=-84.7250, lat=42.3583, method='nearest')
```

I try to convert this slice to a pandas dataframe. The output dataframe I expect would have 8 data variables.

```
df = station.to_dataframe()
```

I am able to convert a single data variable from the slice to a Pandas series in 1.5 minutes using the command:

```
df = station["wind_speed"].to_series()
```

Do I need to change how I read in the large datasets? Or is there a workaround to get to a pandas dataframe faster?

Comment: For now, I am looping through each 1GB netcdf file and individually extracting my slice and converting it to a pandas dataframe. Then after my loop, I concatenate the multiple pandas df into a single df. I would prefer not to loop though...

Comment: can you reproduce this performance difference using two new environments (one with an old version of xarray, one with a new one)? if so, I'm sure the xarray team would love to hear about this as an [issue](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/). it would be really helpful (actually... required) that you provide more info about the datasets you're reading in, especially data types, file layout, dimensions over which you're concatenating, etc. Ideally, turn this into a [mre]. But even just the info I listed above would be a helpful place to start.

Comment: Thank you, I have submitted an issue with more details about my datasets. https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7075